# Let $M$ be the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $N$ and let $M'$ be the algebra generated by $N$.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $N\subset 2^X$. Let $M$ be the $\sigma$ algebra generated by $N$ and let $M'$ be the algebra generated by $N$. What relation must hold between $M$ and $M'$?

My answer: $M$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$ algebras containing $N$, and $M'$ is the intersection of all algebras containing $N$. Since a $\sigma$ algebra containing $N$ is automatically an algebra containing $N$, we have $M\subset M'$.

Is my answer correct? Somehow my professor said it should be $M'\subset M$.

Comment: It's $M' \subset M$ because every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra. See it this way: $A \subset B$ if every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$.

Comment: Yep I see now. $A\cap B\subset B$

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.)*

---

Since every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, $M'$ is contained in every $\sigma$-algebra that contains $N$.

In particular, $M'$ is contained in $M$, which is *a fortiori* a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $N$.